# Threading issue when playing music file

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, soundplayer

What I'm trying to do is play a music file for a specified duration, and then stop playing. However, the whole music file is being played. I cannot use the 'PlaySync()' method as I cannot have the thread being blocked.

Comment: Does `player` has its own `Stop` method?

Comment: Maybe your stop call comes *before* the sound has even started. Workaround would be to start your timer at the start of playback, not at the 'play' request.

Comment: What is `PlaySync()` method and why you need this one?

Comment: I can't find any details regarding this one, am I missed something?

Comment: I said "I cannot use the 'PlaySync()' method as I cannot have the thread being blocked"... why do you assume I 'need' it.

Comment: anyway try out adding `thread.Join()` after the `thread.Start()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe something like this

```
 Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
   {
    var player = new SoundPlayer();
    player.SoundLocation = "myfile";
    player.Play();
    Thread.Sleep(duration)
    player.Stop();
   });
```

Comment: +1 this looks an interesting possibility, why the downvote? (I upvoted too).

Comment: code didn't compile at first version ;) maybe that's the reason

Comment: downvoted because Thread.Sleep is never a good solution (except in very special corner case situations I have never heard about). Moreover this version uses 2 threads (1 for the player.Play() method and one spawned by StartNew), and blocks one of them uselessly

Comment: Anyway I suggest using `thread.Jojn()` to wait whilst "playing" thread would finish its job, basically addign `thread.Join()` after the `thread.Start()`

Comment: @Falanwe thanx for your tips, i find them usefull and probably will never user Thread.Sleep  again ;)

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to spawn a new thread yourself, as the `SoundPlayer.Play` method does it itself.

try this version:

```
public void Play() 
    { 
        player = new SoundPlayer(); 
        player.SoundLocation = "myfile"; 
        Timer timer = new Timer(); 
        timer.Tick += (s,e) => 
            {
                player.Stop();
                timer.Stop();
            };
        timer.Interval = duration; 
        player.Play();
        timer.Start(); 
    }
```